# Why does the cursor often lose focus automatically after entering the full screen?

Tags: macos, apple-silicon

If there is no such annoying problem, I will work with my Mac without shutting it down for several months. However, I have to reboot my Mac for several times a day because my cursor losses focus when I enter a full screen video while this issue( as the title says) happened.

Comment: Define 'lose focus'. If you run fullscreen video, the cursor & any screen decoration should usually fade out & not reappear unless you move the mouse again.

Comment: @Tetsujin By "lose focus", I mean that the focus of the current activity window is not the full screen one, which makes it impossible for me to operate the video by  space or direction keys.

Comment: So it's the app [or window] that loses focus. A couple of things to check - 1. how many displays do you have? 2. If more than one, look at system prefs>Mission Control… is 'displays have separate Spaces' checked or unchecked. 3. if you lift the cursor to the top of the screen does the correct app appear in the menu bar? 4. Is the video running 'solo' in its own app, or is the video running in some generic app like a browser, with several windows open?

Comment: @Tetsujin 1. There's only one displayer. 2.. 3. When the issue occurs, when I enter the full screen, TouchBar will not display the correct App until I click the front full screen window (moving the cursor alone is helpless). 4. Yes, I run the vedio in Browsers, and this issue occues in both Safari and Firefox, Chrome.

Comment: Ah, I've never used a touch bar Mac. I've no idea how they behave, sorry.

Comment: Maybe you are able to solve this issue without using Touchbar, because icons on Touchbar always change as the activity window change, just like the menu bar do. But thanks all the same! @Tetsujin